# Avoid Range Error for min and max attributes & Force Submit the form

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, forms

I have created a form in which there are 2 `input type=number`. Both inputs are mandatory to be filled by the numbers below,between or out of the range given in `min` and `max` attribute provided which may or may not have decimal numbers. If number will be below the `min` range then the text color will turn **ORANGE**, if it is above the `max` range it will turn **RED** and if the number in input value matches the range it will turn **GREEN**, all these validations will be done by **`jQuery`**.

**ISSUE** here is I need to submit `myForm` but because of `min` & `max` attribute I get this tip "Value must be less than or equal to 20" or "Value must be greater than or equal to 10" for the inputs submitted lesser or greater than the range provided in `min` and `max` attributes respectively, because of this my form does not get submitted.
Can anyone tell me where I maybe going wrong or is there any solution for the same.

Link to the code :
**[`JSFIDDLE`](https://jsfiddle.net/the_hardik_sisodia/ucwpsheb/)**

or

Please check the Snippet Below:

```js
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#weight").keyup(function()
    {
        var max = parseInt($('#weight').attr('max'));
        var min = parseInt($('#weight').attr('min'));
        if ($("#weight").val() >= min)
        {
            if ($("#weight").val() <= max)
            {
                $("#weight").css("color", "green");
            }
            else
            {
                $("#weight").css("color", "red");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $("#weight").css("color", "orange");
        }
    });
});




$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#bmi").keyup(function()
    {
        var max = parseInt($('#bmi').attr('max'));
        var min = parseInt($('#bmi').attr('min'));
        if ($("#bmi").val() >= min)
        {
            if ($("#bmi").val() <= max)
            {
                $("#bmi").css("color", "green");
            }
            else
            {
                $("#bmi").css("color", "red");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $("#bmi").css("color", "orange");
        }
    });
});

$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('input').on('keypress', function(e)
    {
        if (e.which == 13)
        {
            switch ($(this).attr('id'))
            {
                case 'weight':
                $('#bmi').focus();
                e.preventDefault();
                break;

                case 'bmi':
                $('#body_fat').focus();
                e.preventDefault();
                break;

                case 'body_fat':
                $('#submit').focus();
                e.preventDefault();
                break;
            }
        }
    });
});
```

```css
input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button, input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button
{
    -webkit-appearance: none; 
    margin: 0; 
}
.newdatatext
{
 height:60px;
 width:100%;
 text-align:center;
 font-weight:bold;
 font-size:300%;
}
#usernewdetailsform
{
 margin-top:6%;
width:100%;
}
#usernewdetailsform label
{
    font-weight:bold;
 font-size:30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form name="myForm" action="" method="POST">
    <label for="weight">Weight :</label>
    <input type="number" name="weight" id="weight" class="newdatatext" placeholder="Weight" min="10" max="20" step=".01" autofocus required>

    <label for="bmi">BMI</label>
    <input type="number" name="bmi" placeholder="BMI" min="10" max="20" id="bmi" step=".01"  class="newdatatext" required>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: don't use min and max for change the color, add "data-min" and "data-max" to your input and use those data for your variable min and max

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `min` and `max` attributes are used by the browsers to perform form validation. If you want to use them to determine jQuery behavior but want to skip browser blocking of form submission due to invalid values, store them as `data-` attributes and read them using the `.attr()` or `.data()` methods of jQuery, e.g.:

```
var max = parseInt($('#weight').attr('data-max'));
```

...or:

```
var max = parseInt($('#weight').data('max'));
```

Also, looking at your code I realized that you are:

1. using multiple DOM ready callbacks. You only need one, and you can put all your logic in it.
2. repeating the same logic repeatedly for multiple input elements. You can always take advantage of the context of a event, using `$(this)` to refer to the jQuery object that has triggered it.
3. containing nested conditional statements that are difficult to read. You can use guard clauses to assign the colors respectively, e.g.:

An example of a guard clause based on your logic:

```
var val = $(this).val();

if (val < min) {
  $(this).css('color', 'orange');
  return;
}

if (val > max) {
  $(this).css('color', 'red');
  return;
}

$(this).css('color', 'green');
```

---

Here is an updated example:

```js
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#weight, #bmi").keyup(function()
    {
        // Cache DOM node, min/max values, and input value
        var $t = $(this);
        var max = parseInt($t.attr('data-max'));
        var min = parseInt($t.attr('data-min'));
        var val = $t.val();
        
        // Use guard clauses
        if (val < min) {
          $t.css('color', 'orange');
          return;
        }
        
        if (val > max) {
          $t.css('color', 'red');
          return;
        }
        
        $t.css('color', 'green');
    });

    $('input').on('keypress', function(e)
    {
        if (e.which == 13)
        {
            switch ($(this).attr('id'))
            {
                case 'weight':
                $('#bmi').focus();
                e.preventDefault();
                break;

                case 'bmi':
                $('#body_fat').focus();
                e.preventDefault();
                break;

                case 'body_fat':
                $('#submit').focus();
                e.preventDefault();
                break;
            }
        }
    });
});
```

```css
input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button, input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button
{
    -webkit-appearance: none; 
    margin: 0; 
}
.newdatatext
{
 height:60px;
 width:100%;
 text-align:center;
 font-weight:bold;
 font-size:300%;
}
#usernewdetailsform
{
 margin-top:6%;
width:100%;
}
#usernewdetailsform label
{
    font-weight:bold;
 font-size:30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form name="myForm" action="" method="POST">
    <label for="weight">Weight :</label>
    <input type="number" name="weight" id="weight" class="newdatatext" placeholder="Weight" data-min="10" data-max="20" step=".01" autofocus required>

    <label for="bmi">BMI</label>
    <input type="number" name="bmi" placeholder="BMI" data-min="10" data-max="20" id="bmi" step=".01"  class="newdatatext" required>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: I tried your code but it does not change the color of the text in the `input`, Like I said above in my question that, If the number will be below the min range then the text color in the input will turn ORANGE, if it is above the max range it will turn RED and if the number in input value matches the range it will turn GREEN, all these validations were done by jQuery. Can you please check your snippet for the same? This is the only condition not working in your snippet

Comment: @HardikSisodia Whoops, there’s a typo in my code: a missing parenthesis. It should be working now.

Answer (score 0):

You can not submit form if values in input fields will be not in the range. 
In your case, you can change in HTML

```
min="10"
```

to

```
data-min="10"
```

and so on. And in JS:

```
var max = parseInt($('#weight').attr('data-min'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the data-min and data-max attributes to skip the validation errors and also action URL is not specified in the above code. So may be bcoz of that form is not submitted.